# setup and deployment msi give error for prerequisite of local db 2012

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, installation, setup-deployment

I have created a Setup.Exe using setup and deployment of visual studio 2017 and I have added prerequisite of SQL local DB 2012.

while installing the .exe on my computer it gives error 'fatal error' and a log file is created. I have an open log file and try to search the error given in the log file, it says that higher version of software i.e. prerequisite software is already installed.

How can I omit if the installation of a prerequisite if a higher version is already installed?

I need help very badly on this. If anyone has any other solution rather than this please let me know.